# How do I get an accurate pointer position on click on top of a draggable layer?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, kineticjs

I'm just learning Kinetic.js, and I really enjoy how easy it's making using the HTML5 `<canvas>` element.

I have a large layer that's bigger than the "stage" (to use Kinetic parlance) but is draggable.  The drag functionality seems to interfere with the click handler in two different ways:  Some single clicks do not register; and and of those that do, the location is only accurate if the layer is in its original position.

[Here's a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/EKaAv/) displaying the issue I'm having.  In my actual code, the bottom layer is actually an image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/EKaAv/1/

```
layer.on ('click', function(e) {
    console.log(e);
    var mousePos = stage.getMousePosition(); // mouse position relative to stage
    var xclick = mousePos.x;
    var yclick = mousePos.y;
    var circle = new Kinetic.Circle({
        x: xclick - layer.getX(), // since position is relative to stage, adjust by layer X
        y: yclick - layer.getY(), // same as above
        radius: 25,
        fill: 'red',
        opacity: 0.5
    });
    layer.add(circle);
    stage.draw();       // redraw the stage immediately
});
```

Any clicks that seem to not be registered are due to the draggable event firing which overrides the click event.

Comment: Brilliant!  The getX() and getY() were exactly what I was looking for, but couldn't find in the documentation.  I'll probably implement 'modes' for moving and editing, so I likely won't have to worry about the arguing event handlers.  Thanks so much.

Comment: I'm not exactly sure why Kinetic complicates getting/modifying the x/y coordinates, but it does. I only know this because I spent some time speed-programming a breakout clone in Kinetic today. :D